# Drag and drop not functioning on dynamically created list

Tags: javascript, drag-and-drop

I have a list of activities that is generated dynamically with javascript in the following manner:

```
const renderList = (activities) => {
  const display = document.getElementById('task-list-display');
  activities.forEach((activity) => {
    console.log(activity);
    display.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', ` 
    <li class="task-item draggable" draggable="true">
      <div class="chk-descr">
        <input data-a1="${activity.index}" type="checkbox" name="completed"/>
        <p data-b1="${activity.index}" class="description" contenteditable="true">${activity.description}</p>
      </div>
    </li> 
    `);
```

I want to have it be responsive in a way that the items can be rearranged using drag and drop. I am not able, however, to make this work. Previously I had designed the very same app but instead of having the items of the list be inserted using `insertAdjacentHTML()` I was creating each element using `createElement()` and then appending it to the corresponding HTML element using `appendChild()`. The drag and drop functionality on that app was fully functioning. My question is: is there some reason why drag and drop might not work with a dynamically generated list using `insertAdjacentHTML?`.

Here is all the relevant code:

```
let activities = [];

const dragstart = (element) => {
  element.classList.add('skateover');
};

const dragover = (element, e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  element.classList.add('dragover');
};

const dragleave = (element) => {
  element.classList.remove('dragover');
};

const drop = (element) => {
  const skateover = document.querySelector('.skateover');
  element.before(skateover);

  repopulateList();
  element.classList.remove('dragover');
};

const dragend = (element) => {
  element.classList.remove('skateover');
};

const repopulateList = () => {
  const listItems = document.querySelectorAll('.draggable');
  emptyList();

  let i = 0;
  listItems.forEach((listItem) => {
    listItem.setAttribute('activity', i);
    i += 1;
    
    const description = listItem.getElementsByClassName('description')[0].textContent;
    const completed = listItem.getElementsByClassName('completed')[0].checked;
    const index = listItem.getAttribute('activity');

    inputActivity(description, completed, index);
  });
};

const inputActivity = (description, completed, index) => {
  activities.push({ description, completed, index: parseInt(index, 10) });
};
```

And in the HTML file:

```
<ul id="task-list-display"></ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is not a problem. Here I add the eventlisteners to the unordered list (`<ul>`). So, the adding, cloning and removing of list items (`<li>`) is not an issue.

There is no problem in using methods like `insertAdjacentHTML()`. In this example I just use `cloneNode()` for cloning the node that is moved and then `insertBefore()` to insert the cloned node before the list item that is hovered/dropped on.

```js
const activities = [{
    index: 1,
    description: "Item 1"
  },
  {
    index: 2,
    description: "Item 2"
  },
  {
    index: 3,
    description: "Item 3"
  }
];

const display = document.getElementById('task-list-display');

const renderList = (activities) => {
  activities.forEach((activity) => {
    display.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', ` 
    <li class="task-item draggable" draggable="true" data-id="${activity.index}">
      <div class="chk-descr">
        <input data-a1="${activity.index}" type="checkbox" name="completed"/>
        <p data-b1="${activity.index}" class="description" contenteditable="true">${activity.description}</p>
      </div>
    </li> 
    `)
  });
};

display.addEventListener("dragstart", e => {
  e.dataTransfer.setData("text/plain", e.target.dataset.id);
});

display.addEventListener("dragover", e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  [...display.querySelectorAll('li')].forEach(li => li.classList.remove('over'));
  e.target.closest('li.task-item').classList.add('over');
});

display.addEventListener("drop", e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  [...display.querySelectorAll('li')].forEach(li => li.classList.remove('over'));
  let original = document.querySelector(`li[data-id="${e.dataTransfer.getData("text/plain")}"]`);
  let clone = original.cloneNode(true);
  let target = e.target.closest('li.task-item');
  display.insertBefore(clone, target);
  display.removeChild(original);
});


renderList(activities);
```

```css
ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

li div {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.over {
  border-top: solid thin black;
}
```

```html
<ul id="task-list-display"></ul>
```